How to replace SWT control?
I have customized a plugin that contains a Button. How can I replace org.aclipse.swt.control.Button ?
example
plugin xxx.xxx.xxx
package xxx.xxx.xxx
public class Button extends Canvas {

}

I think org.cclipse.swt.control.Button is too ugly, I want the IDE to use the Button I wrote

There is no straight forward way to do this.

SWT provides native widgets, so a button looks differently on different operating systems. See here how to create your customized button in SWT.

The method I am currently using is to replace some class files in SWT, and I have succeeded. I am looking for a better way

On macOS, at least, using a different Button class would stop things like the "default" button in a dialog working since it uses macOS APIs which rely on the button being based the correct macOS button class.
